# OnApearing() method is not firing second time in Mater details page of xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, navigation-drawer, master-detail, reloaddata

I'm using a custom master details page. On that page, I implemented the onAppearing() method. It's firing the first time (When I run the program.Master detail page is the root page of my app) only.
When I clicked the hamburger icon to open the Navigation drawer, that OnAppearing() is not firing.

**MasterDetailsPage CS Code:**

```
public partial class MainMasterDetailPage : MasterDetailPage
    {
        public MainMasterDetailPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
            NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
           
            ListOfSettings.IsVisible = false;

            this.IsPresented = false;

            Detail = new NavigationPage(new DashboardTabbedPage());

        }
        protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            ListOfSettings.IsVisible = false;
        }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does it fire when you are minimise you app and then maximise you app? It won't fire when you click menu, because this control in already present. Also do not use async method in OnAppearing if you are not calling async function inside.

Comment: I want to set false for `Isvisible` property for one stack layout...What i have to do for that.

Comment: For the stack layout inside your menu page?

Comment: Yes...See above pics once. The default screen will be displayed like the first screenshot. When I click on `settings` button, sub buttons will open. If I close that screen without closing the sub buttons those are visible when I open the navigation drawer.

Comment: This is obvious that it will not fire because it is not logically Appearing, its always just there, Now for you to update your Hamburger menu @ Runtime you will have to use messaging centre listen to a message and update data accordingly  https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/xamarin-forms-messagingcenter-ab97eb923fd0

Comment: How can I use MessagingCenter in this scenario?

Comment: Do you know how the messaging centre works?

Comment: @FreakyAli I used IsPresentedChanged property. Please check the below code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used `IsPresentedChanged` property. Please check the below code.

```
public MainMasterDetailPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
            ListOfSettings.IsVisible = false;
            this.IsPresented = false;
            Detail = new NavigationPage(new DashboardTabbedPage());

            this.IsPresentedChanged += hideSettingMenu;

        }
        public void hideSettingMenu(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            ListOfSettings.IsVisible = false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to handle this, except messaging center (which can be tricky when passing bool value) is to subscribe to IsPresentedChanged event handler of your master detail page in your menu page. Example pseudo code:

```
namespace TestApp.Views
{
    public partial class MenuPage : ContentPage
    {
        MainPage RootPage { get => Application.Current.MainPage as MainPage; }
        List<HomeMenuItem> menuItems;
        public MenuPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            BindingContext = this;

            menuItems = new List<HomeMenuItem>
            {
                new HomeMenuItem {Id = MenuItemType.Browse, Title="Browse" },
                new HomeMenuItem {Id = MenuItemType.About, Title="About" }
            };




            ListViewMenu.ItemsSource = menuItems;

            ListViewMenu.SelectedItem = menuItems[0];
            ListViewMenu.ItemSelected += async (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (e.SelectedItem == null)
                    return;

                var id = (int)((HomeMenuItem)e.SelectedItem).Id;
                RootPage.IsPresentedChanged += MenuVisibleChanged;
                await RootPage.NavigateFromMenu(id);

            };


        }

        private void MenuVisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //handle your menu visibilty here with calling IsPresented
            var menuIsVisible = RootPage.IsPresented;
        }
    }
}
```